# Работа с иерархическими данными в lsfusion

Tags: lsfusion

В своей статье на Хабре (https://habr.com/ru/company/lsfusion/blog/468047/) Вы показали хороший пример работы с группами и подчиненными данными. Вопрос - а можно ли такую технику применить к одиночному классу без введения дополнительного класса для группировок?

```
CLASS Animal 'Животное';
parent = DATA Animal (Animal);
name 'Отряд/Животное' = DATA STRING[100] (Animal);
areal = DATA STRING[100] (Animal);
```

***И как теперь это все визуализировать в виде дерева в форме?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, техническое решение иерархического представления данных без вспомогательного класса для группировки выглядит следующим образом:

```
CLASS Animal;
parent = DATA Animal(Animal);
name = DATA STRING[50] (Animal);
areal = DATA STRING[50] (Animal);
nameParent (Animal a) = name(parent(a));

// Для редактирования объекта   

FORM animal 
   OBJECTS a = Animal PANEL 
   PROPERTIES(a) name, nameParent, areal

   EDIT Animal OBJECT a
;

// Для представления списка объектов с деревом

FORM animals 
   TREE animal a = Animal PARENT parent(a)
   PROPERTIES(a) READONLY name,  areal
   PROPERTIES(a) NEWSESSION NEW, EDIT, DELETE

   LIST Animal OBJECT a
;

NAVIGATOR {
   NEW animals;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, все равно ждем комментариев по коду от гуру.

Comment: Я немного проконсультировался с коллегами.. У вас в принципе сделано все нормально, единственное, что в данном случае свойство `level` никак не используется и соответственно в этом примере не нужно. Ну и создание формы `animal` для редактирования объектов - это нормально, так делают, но в к данному вопросу эта форма отношения не имеет. Если нужно пояснить, что делает этот код, задавайте вопросы в комментариях.

Comment: TREE animal a = Animal PARENT parent(a) - На эту строку нужны пояснения. Я написал ее по наитию, вообще не понимая как работает ключевое слово TREE.

Comment: Это объявление блока дерева объектов, вот о нем в документации: https://documentation.lsfusion.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3866658#id-%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-tree

Comment: Обновленная ссылка: https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Object_blocks/#tree